# Problemas com host ao conectar dois computadores com socket-py

Tags: python

Olá!

Tenho tentado aprender sobre socket com python. Meu primeiro código seria um programa para conectar um cliente a um servidor e, em seguida, enviar dados. Coloquei o arquivo python do lado do servidor, em outro computador na minha casa.

Aqui está parte do client-side:

```
import socket
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 5000
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
dest = (HOST, PORT)
print("Conectando...")
tcp.connect(dest)
```

E aqui está a parte do server-side:

```
HOST = socket.gethostname()
print(HOST)
PORT = 5000
threads = {}
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
orig = (HOST, PORT)
tcp.bind(orig)
tcp.listen(5)
con, cliente = tcp.accept()
```

Aqui está o erro que recebo. Creio que isso esteja relacionado ao host:

> tcp.connect(dest)
> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente

Tentei colocar na variável host do client-side o ip da minha máquina - servidor - e aparentemente não há resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Seu cliente está apontando para `localhost` enquanto seu server está pegando o nome da máquina com `socket.gethostname()`

No server use:

```
HOST = "localhost"
```

ou

```
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
```

ou ainda

```
HOST = "0.0.0.0"
```

Este último irá fazer o `bind` tanto em localhost quanto no IP da(s) placa(s) de rede

Comment: Utilizando ```HOST = "0.0.0.0"``` e no lado do cliente usando o ip do servidor: Sem resposta do servidor. Já ao usar HOST = "localhost" no lado do cliente diz que o servidor recusou.

Comment: Utilizando no servidor ```HOST = "localhost"``` e no cliente ```HOST = "localhost"``` o servidor recusou. Já utilizando no cliente ```HOST = "ip do servidor"``` não houve resposta.

Comment: Está parecendo um problema de permissão no firewall. Se vc estiver usando Windows (parece ser por conta do erro), abra um `cmd e rode o seu server; depois abra outro `cmd` como administrador, e rode `netstat -a -b`; verifique se a porta TCP 5000 está LISTENING.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/10r4f87 Isso mesmo, está em listening.

Comment: Agita tem que ver o firewall...